# Creating a Cookie in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-mvc-4

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward. However, for the life of me, I can't seem to create a cookie in ASP.NET MVC. Currently, I have the following code:

```
DateTime lastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
if (Request.Browser.Cookies)
{
  HttpCookie lastActivityCookie = new HttpCookie(COOKIE_LAST_ACTIVITY, lastActivityDate.ToShortDateString());
  lastActivityCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);                    
  this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(lastActivityCookie);
}
```

I've set a breakpoint and noticed that the cookie appears to be getting added. (yes, I'm getting into the `Request.Browser.Cookies` block). I then attempt to retrieve the cookie using the following:

```
DateTime lastActivity = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);        // Default to the past week

HttpCookie lastActivityCookie = Request.Cookies[COOKIE_LAST_ACTIVITY];
if (lastActivityCookie != null)
{
  DateTime temp = DateTime.UtcNow;
  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastActivityCookie.Value) == false)
  {
    if (DateTime.TryParse(lastActivityCookie.Value, out temp))
      lastActivity = temp;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `lastActivityCookie` is always `null`. In addition, when I look in the "Resources" tab in Chrome, I see the cookies branch, however, the cookie I'm trying to create is not listed. There are two other cookies listed though, including the .ASPXAUTH cookie. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you set the cookie expires date to Now-12month? AFAIK a cookie that expires in the past should be deleted by the browser so it makes sense it is not even set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the *Expires* property of *HttpCookie* object - more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.expires.aspx). I believe you shoud set cookie expiration date in future like in the example on msdn site. Because you set date time in the past the cookie automatically expires and you are never able to read it.